# Excel VBA Array() function causing type mismatch?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I've created the following function to look for files and give errors if the files aren't found:

```
Public Function checkFileExistence(arrFileNames() As String, Optional bShowErrMsg As Boolean = False) As Boolean
' This function looks for every file name in arrFileNames and returns True if all exist else False
' Optional: bShowErrMsg = True will tell the user which file was missing with a MsgBox
Dim file As Variant

For Each file In arrFileNames
    If Len(Dir(file, vbNormal)) = 0 Then
        checkFileExistence = False
        If bShowErrMsg = True Then MsgBox (file & " was not found.")
        Exit Function
    End If
Next file
checkFileExistence = True
End Function
```

When I go to call it, I get a type mismatch error though. This happens with a predefined array and also when trying to use the Array() function:

```
.
Dim filesToFind(1 To 3) As String
filesToFind(1) = "image.png"
filesToFind(2) = "test.png"
filesToFind(3) = "test.fred"

Debug.Print checkFileExistence(filesToFind, True)
Debug.Print checkFileExistence(Array("image.png", "test.png", "test.fred"), True)
```

This also happens if arrFileNames() is a Variant. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change `arrFileNames() As String` to `arrFileNames As Variant`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Array` doesn't return a typed array (e.g. `String()`).

Change your signature to take a `Variant` instead:

```
Public Function checkFileExistence(arrFileNames As Variant, Optional bShowErrMsg As Boolean = False) As Boolean
```

And you can always validate that you're looking at an actual array, with the `IsArray` function:

```
    If Not IsArray(arrFileNames) Then Err.Raise 5, "CheckFileExistence", "Expected array, but received a " & TypeName(arrFileNames) & "."
```

Also I'd warmly recommend changing your loop to a `For...Next` loop. Arrays don't want to be iterated with `For Each` - see [this article](http://analystcave.com/vba-for-loop-vs-for-each-loop/).

```
For i = LBound(arrFileNames) To UBound(arrFileNames)
```

Comment: Hi Mat - *"Array doesn't returned a typed array".* - Could you elaborate on this for me please? I figured it out by messing around in the module, but I actually have no idea why this works.

Comment: Ah! That did it. The article link is also much appreciated.

Comment: So I guess what I'm wondering is why `arrFilesNames() As Variant` doesn't pass?

Comment: @dwirony I've yet to figure out the correct wording for this, but essentially... the way arrays get passed around in VBA is a bit clunky ;-) `Variant()` says "every item is a `Variant`" (and VBA won't take an `Integer()` or `String()` for it), while `Variant` says "this can be anything including an array of anything".