# VBA: Subscript Out of Range - Size of array index is larger than array size

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I created an array index (`tickerIndex`).

When I run the code, I get the error

> subscript out of range

When I run the code, for some reason, the `tickerIndex` variable counts up to 13 which is 1 more than the size of the array.

The size of the tickers array is 12.

[image]

The tickerIndex variable is used to loop the `tickers`, `tickerVolumes`, `tickerStartingPrices`, and `tickerEndingPrices` arrays.

```
    Dim tickers(12) As String
    
    tickers(0) = "AY"
    tickers(1) = "CSIQ"
    tickers(2) = "DQ"
    tickers(3) = "ENPH"
    tickers(4) = "FSLR"
    tickers(5) = "HASI"
    tickers(6) = "JKS"
    tickers(7) = "RUN"
    tickers(8) = "SEDG"
    tickers(9) = "SPWR"
    tickers(10) = "TERP"
    tickers(11) = "VSLR"
    
    'Activate data worksheet
    Worksheets(yearValue).Activate
    
    'Get the number of rows to loop over
    RowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    
    Dim tickerIndex As Integer
    tickerIndex = 0
    

    
    Dim tickerVolumes(12) As Long
    Dim tickerStartingPrices(12) As Single
    Dim tickerEndingPrices(12) As Single
    
    
    For tickerIndex = 0 To 11
    ticker = tickers(tickerIndex)
    tickerVolumes(tickerIndex) = 0
    
        
       
        Worksheets(yearValue).Activate
        For i = 2 To RowCount
    
            'Increase volume for current ticker [error on this line]
            ***If Cells(i, 1).Value = tickers(tickerIndex) Then***
                tickerVolumes(tickerIndex) = tickerVolumes(tickerIndex) + Cells(i, 8).Value
            End If
        
        
            ' Check if the current row is the first row with the selected tickerIndex.
            If Cells(i - 1, 1).Value <> tickers(tickerIndex) And Cells(i, 1).Value = tickers(tickerIndex) Then
                tickerStartingPrices(tickerIndex) = Cells(i, 6).Value
            End If
        
            'check if the current row is the last row with the selected ticker
            'If the next row's ticker doesn't match, increase the tickerIndex.
            If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> tickers(tickerIndex) And Cells(i, 1).Value = tickers(tickerIndex) Then
                tickerEndingPrices(tickerIndex) = Cells(i, 6).Value
            
            End If

            'Increase the tickerIndex if the next row’s ticker doesn’t match the previous row’s ticker.
            If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then
                tickerIndex = tickerIndex + 1
            
            End If
    
        Next i
    Next tickerIndex

    
    'Loop through arrays to output the Ticker, Total Daily Volume, and Return.
    For i = 0 To 11
        
        Worksheets("AllStocksAnalysis").Activate
        Cells(4 + i, 1).Value = tickers(tickerIndex)
        Cells(4 + i, 2).Value = tickerVolumes(tickerIndex)
        Cells(4 + i, 3).Value = (tickerEndingPrices(tickerIndex) / tickerStartingPrices(tickerIndex)) - 1
        
    Next i
```

Comment: Never modify the counter variable of an for-loop within the loop.

Comment: Why do `tickerIndex = tickerIndex + 1` while the looping is already done by `For tickerIndex = 0 To 11`?

Comment: Side notes: Declare your variables and use `Option Explicit` to force variable declarations. Fully qualify your range references instead of activating worksheets.

Comment: Thanks  @shahkalpesh, I removed the part that was incrementing the tickerIndex ad the code worked fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't hard code your array bounds.

Do this

```
For tickerIndex = LBound(tickers) To UBound(tickers)
    ticker = tickers(tickerIndex)
    ...
```

or better yet this

```
For Each ticker In tickers
    ...
```

instead of this

```
For tickerIndex = 0 To 11
    ticker = tickers(tickerIndex)
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks @NicholasHunter, I referenced the array bounds the way you said, I also removed the block of code that was incrementing the tickerIndex (that was throwing off the count by 1)

Comment: @NicholasHunter Fyi c.f. Mathieu Guindon at [SO post regarding an array function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49056303/excel-vba-array-function-causing-type-mismatch/49056504#49056504) citing *"Also I'd warmly recommend changing your loop to a For...Next loop. Arrays don't want to be iterated with For Each - see this [article](http://analystcave.com/vba-for-loop-vs-for-each-loop/)."*

Comment: @T.M. New info to me. Thanks for that.